# Can i append to a pandas dataframe while i'm looping through JSON data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
WallDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Rate', 'Qty'])
```

In the meantime i'm looping through some data:

```
for x in myData:
    for y in myData['records']:
        print(x['Date'], y[0], y[1])
```

How can i generate a dataframe from that loop, instead of printing? I would like to add the data i'm printing to the dataframe. If it was an array, i would use a simple `append()`, but instead i need to use a dataframe.

Comment: so add to WallDF rows the values in myData?

Comment: please provide a sample data and expected output. the code you shared does not give sufficient context. for instance, if myData is a dictionary, it is unclear to me why you are iterating through it twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside loops you could create a list for data:

```
data = []
```

Inside loops you could add a small dict at each step:

```
data.append({'Date':x['Date'], 'Rate':y[0], 'Qty':y[1]})
```

After the loops convert it efficiently to dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you have `for y in myData['records']` nested inside `for x in myData`.

Regardless, you can use list comprehension here to translate your nested loop & print to construct the data frame.

```
WallDF = pd.DataFrame([
    (myData['Date'], y[0], y[1]) 
    for y in myData['records']
 ],
 columns = ['Date', 'Rate', 'Qty']
)
```

In more recent versions of pandas, you may also use json_normalize

```
WallDF = pd.json_normalize(
  myData, record_path='records', ['Date']
).rename(columns={0: 'Rate', 1:'Qty'})
```

With the following sample data:

```
myData = {'records': [(1.04, 100), (1.07, 200), (1.01, 300)], 
          'Date': '2020-06-22'}
```

the two snippets above respectively produce outputs:

```
         Date  Rate  Qty
0  2020-06-22  1.04  100
1  2020-06-22  1.07  200
2  2020-06-22  1.01  300
```

and

```
   Rate  Qty        Date
0  1.04  100  2020-06-22
1  1.07  200  2020-06-22
2  1.01  300  2020-06-22
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! This works too! About the first line of your answer: myData is a dict, and inside the dict there is a key where it's value is a list of lists with data. So it's like myData = {'data': [], 'date': '..'}